# approximate proportions preserving sum (1 = 100%) in R

Tags: r, approximation, summarization

I have a big table in which I have calculated the number of counts by subcategory `countsperc` (subcategory names not shown)
for every category (`id`), then the total
of observations per category (`id`) in column `sumofcounts`, and the proportion of subcategory to
the total (`counsperc/sumofcounts`) in `apppropor` (approx. proportions), that needs to be approximate (3 decimal). 
The problem is, the sum of approximate proportions (`old_sum`) for categories (`id`) has to be 1.000 instead of 0.999, etc. 
So, I would like to ask for a method to add or subtract 0.001, on any sub-item of column `apppropor` in order to get 1.000 always as the sum.
For example, in row1 the number could be 0.334 instead of 0.333
EDIT: The goal of the task is not to produce solely a exact sum of 1, which has no utility, but to produce an input to other program, which will consider the column `apppropor` as is (requiring it will sum 1.000 per `id`, see error message below).

```
text1<-"
id    countsperc sumofcounts   apppropor     
item1          1           3       0.333     
item1          1           3       0.333     
item1          1           3       0.333     
item2          1         121       0.008     
item2        119         121       0.983     
item2          1         121       0.008     
item3          1          44       0.023    
item3          1          44       0.023     
item3         41          44       0.932     
item3          1          44       0.023     
item4          1          29       0.034     
item4          3          29       0.103      
item4          1          29       0.034   
item4         24          29       0.828"
table1<-read.table(text=text1,header=T)
library(data.table)
sums<-as.data.frame(setDT(table1)[, sum(`apppropor`), by = .(id)][,.(id, old_sum = V1)])
table1<-merge(table1,sums)
table1
```

> chromEvol Version: 2.0. Last updated December 2013
>
> The count probabilities for taxa Ad_mic not sum to
>   1.0 chromEvol: errorMsg.cpp:41: static void errorMsg::reportError(const string&, int): Assertion `0' failed.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way.

```
table1$dif<-1-table1$old_sum
table1<-table1[order(table1$id),]
len<-rle(as.vector(table1$id))[[1]]
table1$apppropor[cumsum(len)]<-table1$apppropor[cumsum(len)]+table1$dif[cumsum(len)]
#verify
library(data.table)
sums<-as.data.frame(setDT(table1)[, sum(`apppropor`), by = .(id)][,.(id, new_sum = V1)])
table1<-merge(table1,sums)
table1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need `sum_of_prop` to be identically equal to 1 in every row, you're calculating it the wrong way. You don't add 0.333 + 0.333 + 0.333 and then force that sum to be 1. You add (1/3) + (1/3) + (1/3) and then the sum actually is 1.

Assuming that no other column can change, try calculating `sum_of_prop` like this:

```
n <- length(table1$id)
new_sum_of_prop <- rep(0, n)
for (i in 1:n) {
  tempitem <- table1$id[i]
  tempsum <- sum(table1$countsperc[(table1$id == tempitem)])
  new_sum_of_prop[i] <- table1$sumofcounts[i] / tempsum
}

table2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(table1, new_sum_of_prop))
table2
      id countsperc sumofcounts apppropor sum_of_prop new_sum_of_prop
1  item1          1           3     0.333       0.999               1
2  item1          1           3     0.333       0.999               1
3  item1          1           3     0.333       0.999               1
4  item2          1         121     0.008       0.999               1
5  item2        119         121     0.983       0.999               1
6  item2          1         121     0.008       0.999               1
7  item3          1          44     0.023       1.001               1
8  item3          1          44     0.023       1.001               1
9  item3         41          44     0.932       1.001               1
10 item3          1          44     0.023       1.001               1
11 item4          1          29     0.034       0.999               1
12 item4          3          29     0.103       0.999               1
13 item4          1          29     0.034       0.999               1
14 item4         24          29     0.828       0.999               1
```

I understand that this isn't exactly what you asked for, but in the long run, your results are always healthier if you don't cut mathematical corners along the way.

Comment: thanks, but the focus is the column apppropor. see edit.